# Enum to dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

I want to implement an extension method which converts an enum to a dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> ToDictionary(this Enum @enum)
{
    Type type1 = @enum.GetType();
    return Enum.GetValues(type1).Cast<type1>()
        //.OfType<typeof(@enum)>()
        .ToDictionary(e => Enum.GetName(@enum.GetType(), e));
}
```

Why it doesn't compile?

An error:

> "The type or namespace name 'type1'
> could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly
> reference?)"

Comment: Why don't you show us the error message?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[Jon Skeet has written everything you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5500194/655372) ;)

But here you have your code that is working:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> ToDictionary(this Enum @enum)
{
  var type = @enum.GetType();
  return Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<int>().ToDictionary(e => e, e => Enum.GetName(type, e));
}
```

Comment: You can simplify it slightly by writing `Cast<int>` instead of `Cast<object>`, because then you can omit the cast from object to int in the first lambda-expression.

Comment: This isn't going to work for all Enum underlying types.  Also check that `typeof(int) == Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type)`.

Comment: If you're using the lowercase type of `enum`, use `typeof(@enum)` instead of `@enum.GetType()`.

Comment: Can you show an example usage? this isn't showing up for me.

Comment: public enum SomeEnum { A, B, C }

and the usage:
var d = SomeEnum.A.ToDictionary();

Comment: @Rafal So your saying you reference one of the enum values and then call the function against it? Doesnt the function take a parameter of (this Enum @enum)?

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle yes, the method takes enum value, so you need to pass one. Otherwise you can't say that method takes enum - it could take type, but then it would be any type.

Answer (score 13):

Well, you're trying to use a *variable* of type `Type` as a generic type argument. You can't do that with generics, which are about *compile-time* types.

You can do it with reflection, but it would be better to make it a generic method. Unfortunately you can't constrain a generic type parameter to be an enum, although I have some hacks to work around that in [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/).

Failing that, you could use just a `struct` type constraint for a generic method which would be a good start.

Now, the next problem is that you're trying to get a `Dictionary<int, string>` - but the values of an enum *aren't* `int` values. They might be *convertable* to `int` values, but they aren't there immediately. You could use `Convert.ToInt32` to do that, but you would have to do *something*.

Finally (for the moment) what would you expect to happen with an enum using a `uint` or `long` underlying type?

Answer (score 5):

You can't use type1 as a generic parameter, because it is a variable, not a type.

The following code does something *similar* to what your code shows:

```
public static Dictionary<string, TEnum> ToDictionary<TEnum>()
    where TEnum : struct
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enumeration");
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>().
            ToDictionary(e => Enum.GetName(typeof(TEnum), e));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
ToDictionary<Colors>()
```

But I am not really sure, this is, what you expected?

Additionally, it has one problem: You can pass any struct, not just enums and this will result in a runtime exception. See [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500173/enum-to-dictionary/5500194#5500194) for more details about that.

Comment: It's not what I expect. I want to use extension method.

Comment: Show a code sample of your usage and the expected output. (Because it doesn't seem to make sense to invoke this as an extension method)

Comment: @Alex Maslakov: an extension method is not really appropriate here as you are building a dictionary from the data about the enum that is available statically (i.e. it is data in the enum type definition rather than using the properties of a particular enum value). Extension methods operate on an instance of a type.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Daniel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500173/enum-to-dictionary/5500193#5500193):

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this HtmlHelper h) where TEnum : struct
{
    return new SelectList(FortunaExtension.ToDictionary<TEnum>(), "Key", "Value");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the extension method I use to convert enumerations. The only difference is that I am returning IEnumerbale<KeyValuePair<int, int>> for my purpose:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> ToListOfKeyValuePairs<TEnum>(this TEnum enumeration) where TEnum : struct
{
    return from TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
            select new KeyValuePair<int, string>
                (
                    (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), e.ToString()),
                    Regex.Replace(e.ToString(), "[A-Z]", x => string.Concat(" ", x.Value[0])).Trim()
                );
}
```

It also adds spaces for the value.

Example:

```
enum Province
{
    BritishColumbia = 0,
    Ontario = 1
}
```

Usage:

```
<select>
<% foreach(var item in Province.BritishColumbia.ToListOfKeyValuePairs()){ %>
    <option value="<%=item.Key %>"><%=item.Value %></option>
<% } %>
</select>
```

Output:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">British Columbia</option>
    <option value="1">Ontario</option>
</select>
```

Though @Paul Ruane is correct I have found this to be a very useful extension method. It's not a perfect world.