# Passing An Enum Type As An Argument?

Tags: c#, winforms, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# enums as function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492115/c-enums-as-function-parameters)

I was wondering how I can pass an enum type as a method argument.

I'm trying to create a generic method that will take a combo box, and enum, and fill the combo box with each item of the enum.

Comment: what is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refering to [Convert Enum To Dictionary](http://byatool.com/utilities/another-silly-method-just-for-you/):

```
public static IDictionary<String, Int32> ConvertEnumToDictionary<K>()
{
 if (typeof(K).BaseType != typeof(Enum))
 {
   throw new InvalidCastException();
 }

 return Enum.GetValues(typeof(K)).Cast<Int32>().ToDictionary(currentItem => Enum.GetName(typeof(K), currentItem));
}
```

Then you can fill your ComboBox with the returned dictionary items.

Refer to the following as well:

[Dictionary enumeration in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676880/dictionary-enumeration-in-c)

[Enum to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500173/enum-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 19):

I think this is best explained by an example:

Say you have an enum:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

You can declare a method like:

```
    public static void MyEnumMethod(Enum e)
    {
        var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(e.GetType());

        // you can iterate over enumValues with foreach
    }
```

And you would call it like so:

```
MyEnumMethod(new MyEnum());
```

Answer (score 8):

You can pass an enum generically like this:

```
private void Method(Enum tEnum)
{
    Enum.GetValues(tEnum.GetType());
}
```

And the GetValues will give you the values that are possible for that enum.

Usage would be a little odd:

```
Method(EnumType.Value)
```

so it might not fit as well as other ideas.

Answer (score 5):

Using this method, you cann add any type of enum like this: `AddItems(myCombobox, typeof(Options))`

```
  public void AddItems (ComboBox cboBox, Type enumType)
  {
     cboBox.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues (enumType).Cast<object> ().ToArray ());
  }

  enum Options
  {
     Left, Right, Center
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumType))
```

and just populate the combo box items from that

Edit: and of course use reflection to get the enum type :)

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe use a kind of generic enum helper like here : http://devlicious.com/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2007/09/13/my-new-little-friend-enum-lt-t-gt.aspx.

Comment: I was about to post that is exactly the same as what is at the end of that link.